# Python: Split list of dicts by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

If I have a bunch of dicts in a list like:

```
people = [{"name": "Abe", "age": 40},
          {"name": "Bob", "age": 25},
          {"name": "Charles", "age": 32}]
```

I want to split it so it looks like

```
names = ["Abe", "Bob", "Charles"]
ages = [40, 25, 32]
```

I know I can do two separate list comprehensions (ex: `names = [person["name"] for person in people`] twice), but is there any trick to split this data in a one-liner?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) trick:

```
>>> names, ages = zip(*(d.values() for d in people))
>>> names
('Abe', 'Bob', 'Charles')
>>> ages
(40, 25, 32)
```

Note that this will only work on Python 3.7 and later as dictionaries are [insertion ordered](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) in those versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and `map` `dict.values` to the list:

```
names, ages = zip(*map(dict.values, people))
```

---

```
>>> names
('Abe', 'Bob', 'Charles')
>>> ages
(40, 25, 32)
```

Of course they are tuples but that's easy enough to resolve by mapping list to the unzipped result:

```
names, ages = map(list, zip(*map(dict.values, people)))
```

---

```
>>> names
['Abe', 'Bob', 'Charles']
>>> ages
[40, 25, 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dicts share structure (same set of keys), you can aggregate values per key with:

```
>>> import operator
>>> keys = people[0].keys()
>>> getter = operator.itemgetter(*keys)
>>> dict(zip(keys, zip(*map(getter, people))))
{'name': ('Abe', 'Bob', 'Charles'), 'age': (40, 25, 32)}
```

Works in any Python (ordered dict not required), and it's handy for large number of keys/variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with list comprehension extracting the field names you want from the dictionaries:

```
people = [{"name": "Abe", "age": 40},
          {"name": "Bob", "age": 25},
          {"name": "Charles", "age": 32}]

names,ages = ([p[field] for p in people] for field in ("name","age"))

print(names)  # ['Abe', 'Bob', 'Charles']

print(ages)   # [40, 25, 32]
```